# Как заставить фиксированный блок прилипнуть к футеру при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть фиксированный блок внизу экрана

```
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
```

Как его заставить прилипнуть к верхней части футера, когда страница прокручена до футера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: sticky` + filament group [Fixed-sticky polyfill](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #000;
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.aside__sticky {
  position: sticky;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  height: 300px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article></article>
  <aside>
    <div class="aside__sticky"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Как то так, или вы что-то другое имели в виду?

```js
$(window).on('scroll.a', function() {
var a = $('#a').position().top-$(window).height()
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=a){
        $('.fixed').css({'position':'relative','bottom':'85px'})
        $(window).off('scroll.a');
    }
})
```

```css
.fixed{position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
    background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div><div id="a">m</div></div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div class="fixed">a</div>
```

Comment: видимо, не то)) вот http://santech.icms.space/ тут блок плавает, мне нужно, чтобы когда страницу докрутили до футера, он оставался над футером

Comment: зашел я на ваш сайт, и прописал классу "main-bottom" "position:relative;"
и он прилип.
То-есть даже боттом не нужно ему было задавать в моем скрипте.